# URL syntax and display options?

Tags: google-sheets

I recently came across a Google Sheets that had a slightly different syntax in the URL. I found these tags after the Spreadsheet Key:

`&single=true&gid=0&range=B5%3AB5&output=html`

I experimented by putting each of these at the end of one of my docs and discovered some things changed as a result:

`&single=true`
`&gid=0`
`&range=B5%3AB5`
`&output=html`

I was particularly interested in `&range=`. When I chose a regular range such as `A1:B2` it also worked.

But why `&range=B5%3AB5`?

What does it mean and how do I use it?

Comment: `&range=B5%3AB5` is the same as `&range=B5:B5` ([url encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding))

Comment: `&output=pdf` generates the sheet as a PDF.

Answer (score 4):

This link has a few of the ones you mentioned and some you didn't

[Reference Guide - Google Spreadsheets API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/2.0/reference.html#Parameters)

some of the page is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The special characters are encoded using [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). If you have to use special characters in the URL, you will need to encode them. You can use a web app such as [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) for doing the same.