# Using URL to populate Google Sheets cells

Tags: google-sheets, links

If I have a user click a URL for a Google Sheet but append the URL they click with parameters (ie. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0qkLWp3fUm3xpp328MnIz8W4JdBR0990oPU8YW8G0E/edit?playerID=987654`) where playerID is the parameter I want to copy into cell A1 of the Google Sheet in the link, how do I do this? If I can just pass the entire URL to cell A1, that's fine, I'll parse out the variable in a function.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Google Sheets doesn't include that as a built-in feature. Anyway, please add a more details, does the URL could be any URL or should be the spreadsheet URL? Have you considered to use Google Apps Script? P.S. This question might may evolve into asking for a software recommendation... that type off question are off-topic here but might be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: the URL would be the URL for the google sheet where the cell would be populated with the URL value

Comment: basically, I run a fantasy baseball league and host all the stats in google sheets. I have a google sheet that lists all the players, and I would like each player to be a hyperlink so that when the user clicks on that players hyperlink, it takes them to another google sheet where I have a template that looks up the player's statistics based on the playerID in cell A1. I would like the hyperlink to include playerID in the the URL as a parameter, so that when the stats google sheet opens, it populates A1 with the playerID value from the URL parameter. Hopefully that helps clarify things

Comment: Thanks for replying. As I mentioned previously, Google Sheets doesn't include that as a built-in feature, but it support cell links. Have you tried to use them instead of custom query strings?

Comment: Hi. I think that you can do what you are asking, but your parameters have to comply with Google's URL parameters. Have you read [All Google Docs URL parameters/functions/commands?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130655/196152) or [Link to a cell in a Google Sheets via URL?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/44473/196152) or [URL syntax and display options?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16837/196152) - they're all on webapps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All Google Docs URL parameters/functions/commands?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands)